# Swift compare dates iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone tell me why this doesn’t work right with dates from the server?
I'm trying to compare dates to Now so I can see what was in the past, today and future.

```
func getDetails(for game: Game) -> String {
    let now = Date.now
    let gameDate = game.gameDate
    if gameDate.compare(now) == .orderedAscending {
      print(“past”)
      return "past"
    }
    if gameDate.compare(now) == .orderedDescending {
      print(“future”)
      return "future"
    }
    if gameDate.compare(now) == .orderedSame {
      print(“today”)
      return "today"
    }
    return "none"
  }
```

My decoder is set decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
All of the dates come back “past” and this is iOS 15+
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what data the server sends, how you parse that to a `Date` and what value you get if you print `game.gameDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use the compare() function for dates. Dates conform to the Comparable and Equatable protocols, which means you can use `>`, `<`, `=` `>=`, and `<=` to compare them directly.

That said, we don't know what your game.date value is.

I can tell you that Date objects capture the date and time with sub-millisecond precision. Any date you pass into your function is likely to be a few nanoseconds before this code runs, and so be in the past.

consider this code:

```
let now = Date()

var total = 1
total *= 2

let later = Date()

let equalString = (now == later) ? "equal" : "not equal"
print("The dates are \(equalString)")
if now != later {
    print("Dates differ by \(later.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")
}
```

That code prints "The dates are not equal" because it takes enough time to multiply 1 * 2 that the `later` date is a tiny fraction of a second later than `now`.

(On my machine it says that the later date is greater than the `now` date by 8.499622344970703e-05, or about 8.4 microseconds.)

Take out the math code between the two statements and sometimes you'll get it to say the dates are equal, and other times it will say they are not equal.